# Handling JavaScript events not handled by other elements

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am writing a script where I would like to handle mouse events only if they have not been handled by any other element before.

I can attach an event listener to the document object, but it will receive all events regardless of whether they have been already handled.

I have no control over the elements in the HTML page so I cannot manually `stopPropagation()` when the event is handled.

Any ideas?

Comment: How are the click events that you don't control being bound?

Comment: I can't really know, since this is part of a library that may be used with different kind of pages. Could be addEventListener or onXXX.

Comment: Yeah, `addEventListener` makes it harder. For the on[event] types, you could have it so your handler bound to the document starts with the `e.target`, and tests it and its ancestors to see which one had the handler, then wrap it with a function that calls `stopPropagation`. But `addEventListener` won't let you do that.

Comment: @cliffsofinsanity: If the assumptions you made are true, that would be the answer. :)

Comment: @RobinMaben: Except that it won't work for handlers bound with `addEventListener`, because to my knowledge there's no way to ask an element if it had a handler bound. I mean I guess it's a partial answer, but there may be another way that I haven't thought of

Comment: @cliffsofinsanity: Can't we do `$(element).data('events')` and search for the the event types being handled?

Comment: @RobinMaben: That would assume jQuery was being used. It will only work for elements that have handlers in jQuery's event system. Sounds like Grodriguez is looking for a general solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this article **[here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html)**.

It seems its not yet possible to do this.

> Which event handlers are registered?
>
> One problem of the current implementation of W3C’s event registration
>   model is that you can’t find out if any event handlers are already
>   registered to an element. In the traditional model you could do:
>
> `alert(element.onclick)`
>
> and you see the function that’s registered to
>   it, or undefined if nothing is registered. Only in its very recent DOM
>   Level 3 Events W3C adds an

`eventListenerList`

> to store a list of event
>   handlers that are currently registered on an element. *This
>   functionality is not yet supported by any browser*, it’s too new.
>   However, the problem has been addressed.
>
> Fortunately

```
removeEventListener()
```

> doesn’t give any errors if the event
>   listener you want to remove has not been added to the element, so when
>   in doubt you can always use removeEventListener().

Comment: OK.. (although I don't really need a list of listeners). Let's see if I can find some other way.

Answer (score 1):

So, you can accomplish something like you want under a certain set of circumstances.  Specifically, if

- You can load your own custom JavaScript before the original
- You know which elements you are listening for others to throw events on

Effectively, what you do is replace the original addEventListener method on the target element with a custom one that intercepts the call, does some special processing, and then lets it continue per normal.  This 'special processing' is a new function that wraps the original callback, and marks the event arguments with some state to let you know someone else handeled the event already.  Here is a proof of concept (with a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qDfY4/))

Target HTML:

```
<div id='asdf'>asdf</div>​
```

JavaScript:

```
var target = document.getElementById('asdf');
var original = target.addEventListener;

var updated = function(){
    // Grab the original callback, so we can use it in our wrapper
    var originalFunc = arguments[1];

    // Create new function for the callback, that lets us set a state letting us know it has been handled by someone
    // Finish the callback by executing the original callback
    var newFunc = function(e){
        console.log('haha,  intercepted you');
        e.intercepted = true;
        originalFunc.call(this, e);
    };

    // Set the new function in place in the original arguments 'array'
    arguments[1] = newFunc;

    // Perform the standard addEventListener logic with our new wrapper function
    original.apply(this, arguments);
};

// Set the addEventListener on our target to our modified version
target.addEventListener = updated;

// Standard event handling
target.addEventListener('click', function(e){ 
    console.log('original click'); 
    console.log('intercepted?', e.intercepted);
})
```

Comment: This is an interesting idea. I can ensure that my JS will run before the original. However I have no way to know which elements will add an event listener. Is there any way to do this but in a global way? (i.e. globally replacing the addEventListener code with a modified version)